# Convert 11/1/2012 3:42:09 AM to November 1 , 2012

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string representing date (mysql database DateTime)  i want to convert it to custom format as **MMMM d ,YYYY**

Eg. Convert 11/1/2012 3:42:09 AM  to  **November 1 , 2012**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want November as the month, you may use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) and later format the date using `.ToString`

```
string str = "11/1/2012 3:42:09 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDateStr = dt.ToString("MMMMM d, yyyy");
```

EDIT: (from comment of [@Martin Liversage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98607/martin-liversage)

```
//To ignore regional settings. 
string formattedDateStr = dt.ToString("MMMMM d, yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Note that this will produce the string `ноября 1, 2012` if run on a computer with Russian regional settings. The fix is easy of course: just use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as it is already used while parsing the string.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, thanks for pointing it out, I edited the question with due reference :)

Answer (score 2):

`Parse` it into a `DateTime` object, then call `ToString`:

```
string myDate = "11/1/2012 3:42:09 AM";
string formatted = DateTime.Parse(myDate).ToString("MMMM d ,yyyy");
```

---

Note, if the machine you are on does not have the same culture as `myDate` (for example you have European date formats which put the day first), you can specify the input format as well with `ParseExact`:

```
string formatted = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMMM d ,yyyy");
```

Comment: This will give you `"January 11 ,YYYY"`

Comment: @Habib Not on my system it won't. Your dates are backwards :-D

Comment: @Champ, I think its about our machine culture, you may use ParseExact

Comment: Yes it's your machine culture. Just use the ParseExact, specify the Invariant culture, or better yet do both.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you already have a `DateTime` value. To convert it to the desired string you can use this format:

```
dateTime.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Notice the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. This ensures that English month names are used because the invariant culture is based on American culture. Otherwise the current culture is used and that might have different month names.

If the date is retrieved from the database as a `String` and not a `DateTime` then you need to parse the string first:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
  str,
  "MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]